# How do I copy a message and send it again with my discord bot?

Tags: python, discord.py

The title explains it. I have the id of the message I want to copy and send, as well as the id of the channel from where it comes and the channel to where it should be sent. It's an embed message sent by Discohook and I want to send it from my own bot. I tried something like this:

```
def runDiscordBot():
    TOKEN = ""
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", intents = discord.Intents.all())

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        channel = client.get_channel(1094649315810611202)
        message = await channel.fetch_message(1096173976688001134)
        await channel.send(message.content)
        print(f'{client.user} is now running!')

    client.run(TOKEN)
```

When I run this code, this is the error I'm getting:

```
2023-04-13 23:30:58 ERROR    discord.client Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\birea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\birea\Desktop\Programi\FARKBot\tempCodeRunnerFile.python", line 12, in on_ready
    await channel.send(message.content)
  File "C:\Users\birea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1561, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, params=params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\birea\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 744, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message
```

I expected it to send a message that is similar to the one from the id I provided, however it resulted in an error. When I print(message.content), the output just shows an empty line, while doing print(message) results in this:

```
<Message id=1096173976688001134 channel=<TextChannel id=1094649315810611202 name='general' position=0 nsfw=False news=False category_id=1094649315810611200> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<User id=1096121542745788426 name='FARKBot' discriminator='0000' bot=True> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many messages that use `embeds` do not have `content` (this is the textual part above the embed).
Discord doesn't allow you to send an empty message, that's why you are getting this error. If you want to copy the `embed` of a message, use [message.embeds](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.embeds):

```py
def runDiscordBot():
    TOKEN = ""
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", intents = discord.Intents.all())

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
        channel = client.get_channel(1094649315810611202)
        message = await channel.fetch_message(1096173976688001134)
        content = message.content
        embed = message.embeds[0] if message.embeds else None
        await channel.send(content=content, embed=embed)
        print(f'{client.user} is now running!')

    client.run(TOKEN)
```

In this way you are copying the `content` and `embed` of the message.